# Color of scrollbar is still unchanged

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

***functionality:***

Have a container of text, where user can scroll to view more text. The scrollbar is suppose to display a color of `#cab34e`.

***What I have done:***

I have tried implementing the background color in the CSS and making use of `:-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`.

***Issue:***
The scroll bar color is still unchanged. The background color of the scrollbar is still in default color.

Hence, what have I done incorrect?

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 383px;
  left: 602px;
  height: 458px;
  width: 766px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.innerScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #cab34e;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.innerScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #cab34e;
}
.innerScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: #cab34e;
}
.context {
  position: relative;
  width: 730px;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: FuturaLTBook;
  text-align: justify;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="innerScroll">
    <div class="context">
      <p><font face="FuturaBook">TEST TEXT......</font>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: webkit is a rendering engine for browsers such as Google Chrome, safari  or Opera. -- what browser are you testing on ??-- even if you got it working havvng an overall customization of a srcrolbar may be a pain for cross browser implementation -- might be better to use a plugin -- https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar

Comment: @Tasos I am only using this on Google Chrome. I am not planning for cross browser testing

Comment: ok. looking at you css code one more time, i dont think you can just customize it for a container. you could however customize it for the overall browser. hence why this dont work (.innerScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {) but this will (::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {) -- check here https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: i take that back :)) its been a few years since i messed around with scrollbars -- you can actually customize  it for containers -- nice demo here -- http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars/

Comment: @Tasos, I followed, the example in https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/, but it is still not rendering the color intended. That is very strange.

Comment: try the code from the demo -- http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars/

Comment: @Tasos Thanks!!  I got it!!=)))